# WordPress pagination issue

Tags: wordpress

On the [page](http://dev.medcentrperm.ru/author/vegetarianna?posttype=foods) pagination does not work correctly. Ten pages are displayed. In this case, the transition to the tenth does not display posts. After the transition to the second page, the tenth number disappears.
Tried to use the [function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination) `<? Php the_posts_pagination ($ args); ?>` - the result is the same. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try refresh permalinks? Also is there any `posts_per_page => X` argument inside `$args` conflicting with the posts per page under the Settings > Reading?

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I tried to refresh, but it did not work. 
I also tried to change posts per page under the Settings > Reading but it did not work. 
Where can I find "posts_per_page=X"?

Comment: It's normally something put into the $args but the default should be in place if nothing's there.

Comment: So, there is no conflict.

Comment: Just checking, do you have any posts that are not published? If so, try to publish?

Comment: I tried to publish, but there's no effect.

Comment: I explicitly specified 'posts_per_page' argument inside $args '<?php the_posts_pagination( array( 'posts_per_page' => 12 ) ); ?>'. Same result.
Partially solved problem of posts display (10 page) by adding the following code to function.php: https://pastebin.com/tqbg6Gb4. As I found out, this problem occurs when permalinks are configured to look like this:  /%category%/%postname%/
However, now when you click on the tenth page number, it displays the contents of the ninth page. And also after the transition to the second, the tenth number disappears. What to do?